# How to automatically update data from the 12 most recent weeks?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I would like to create two **dynamic weekly** BigQuery Firebase Reports, reflecting the most recent 12 Weeks of data for:

1. Event Occurrences per Week
2. DISTINCT Users who triggered Event Occurrences per Week

The inspiration for these reports came from a [Tableau-report](https://public.tableau.com/profile/amarpal.singh#!/vizhome/BigQueryDailyRowCountforAllEvents/BigQueryDailyRowCountsforallEvents) I saw online:

[image]

I am trying to create dynamic timestamps to pull the values of *1.count of event.name* and *2.distinct user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id*.

**My First Iteration:**

```
SELECT  event.name as event_name, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170724' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170731' THEN event.name END) AS W1,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170731' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170807' THEN event.name END) AS W2,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170807' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170814' THEN event.name END) AS W3,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170814' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170821' THEN event.name END) AS W4,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170821' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170828' THEN event.name END) AS W5,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170828' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170904' THEN event.name END) AS W6,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170904' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170911' THEN event.name END) AS W7,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170911' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170918' THEN event.name END) AS W8,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170918' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20170925' THEN event.name END) AS W9,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170925' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20171002' THEN event.name END) AS W10,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20171002' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20171009' THEN event.name END) AS W11,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20171009' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20171016' THEN event.name END) AS W12  
FROM `<<project-id>>.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE  _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20170724' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20171016'
GROUP BY event_name
ORDER BY event_name DESC;
```

I also played around with sudo code below:

> ```
> # Enable StandardSQL
> SELECT week, event.name as event_name, COUNT(event.name) as event_count
> FROM 
> (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([firebase-analytics-sample-data:android_dataset.app_events_],DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'WEEK'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'WEEK'))), ....
> ....
> ....
> (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([firebase-analytics-sample-data:android_dataset.app_events_],DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -12, 'WEEK'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -12, 'WEEK'))),
> UNNEST(event_dim) as event
> GROUP BY event_name
> ORDER BY week DESC
> LIMIT 12;
> ```
>
> Note: wildcard table does not support views. The query returns an error
>   if the wildcard table matches any views in the dataset. Currently,
>   cached results are not supported for queries against multiple tables
>   using a wildcard function (even if the Use Cached Results option is
>   checked). If you run the same wildcard query multiple times, you are
>   billed for each query. Wildcard tables support native BigQuery storage
>   only. You cannot use wildcards when querying an external table or a
>   view ([source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables)).

**To summarise:**

- It would be a lot faster if I did not have to manually input the date fields every week, but the script "knows" the current [week's index number](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2017) we are in, and updates the 12 most recent weeks' data.

**Appendix**

- Week 30  July 24, 2017   July 30, 2017   20170724    20170730
- Week 31  July 31, 2017   August 6, 2017  20170731    20170806
- Week 32  August 7, 2017  August 13, 2017 20170807    20170813
- Week 33  August 14, 2017 August 20, 2017 20170814    20170820
- Week 34  August 21, 2017 August 27, 2017 20170821    20170827
- Week 35  August 28, 2017 September 3, 2017   20170828    20170903
- Week 36  September 4, 2017   September 10, 2017  20170904    20170910
- Week 37  September 11, 2017  September 17, 2017  20170911    20170917
- Week 38  September 18, 2017  September 24, 2017  20170918    20170924
- Week 39  September 25, 2017  October 1, 2017 20170925    20171001
- Week 40  October 2, 2017 October 8, 2017 20171002    20171008
- Week 41  October 9, 2017 October 15, 2017    20171009    20171015

Comment: What exactly is your question!? ;-)

Comment: I re-wrote this question to be more clearer. Can you up-vote it again please ? And perhaps share your wisdom on how to approach this problem please.

Comment: In my opinion, this question is far too broad and isn't a fit for Stack Overflow. I'd suggest trying something yourself first, then come back with more specific questions and breaking those questions up.

Comment: I created a more defined question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It would be a lot faster if i did not have to manually input the date fields every week), but the script "knows" the week-number we are in, and updates the 12 most recent weeks' data given the week we are in.

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
  BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 12 * 7 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 2 DAY)) 
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY))
```

Below just shows the output

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 * 7 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 2 DAY)) first_day,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY)) last_day
```

-

```sql
first_day   last_day     
20171002    20171015
```

Whenever you run above script  - it will return you the start and end of most recent 12 weeks period

Update for:

> I posted my first iteration answer above in what i would want

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    FORMAT_DATE('Week %W %d %B %Y, ', first_day),
    FORMAT_DATE('%d %B %Y, ', last_day), 
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d ', first_day),
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', last_day)
  ) wk
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 * 7 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 2 DAY) first_day,
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY) last_day 
)
```

with the output

```sql
wk   
Week 41 09 October 2017, 15 October 2017, 20171002 20171015
```

Comment: one question at a time on SO!! so `plug into Google Data Studio` is for sure another question that I recommend you to post as a separate question! meantime, see my update for `extra` formatting. any new and/or follow up questions  - please post as a new question(s)!!!

Comment: Thanks for the update, still missing "Count of Event Occurrences" per week. Where would I actually count this value ? Your script only indicates the output tables dates at this moment, whereas I want to report on count of event_names per week, or am I missing something ? Thanks again for the patience :)