# Dynamic Weekly Date Range in BigQuery for Most Recent 3 Weeks

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

To query distinct events in BigQuery, I want to (firstly) determine previous dates dynamically and (secondly) replace them in my script at the bottom of this question. This will prevent me from having to manually update these dates every week, irregardless when I pull this query (which is an important factor for me).

The first task for me was to dynamically determine the previous weeks' starting and end dates according to [ISO week date standard (ISO-8601)](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2017):

[image]

At the time of writing (31 October 2017), the output for the following 2 queries were: 2017-10-23 (previous Monday) and 2017-10-29 (recent Sunday). One can then change one of the values and get the previous 2 weeks as well. So far, so good!

> Previous Monday:
>
> ```
> # Legacy SQL
> select date(date_add(current_date(), if(dayofweek(current_date()) = 1, -6, -(dayofweek(current_date()) + 5)), "DAY"))
> ```
>
> Most recent Sunday:
>
> ```
> # Legacy SQL 
> select date(date_add(current_date(), if(dayofweek(current_date()) = 1, -6, -(dayofweek(current_date()) - 1)), "DAY"))
> ```

**The question is then:**

- How can I migrate my SQL-code (below) from **Legacy** to **Standard** SQL and replace **all** static dates below with (above-mentioned) dynamic dates ?

> ```
> # Standard SQL
> SELECT
> event.name as event_name,
> COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20171009' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20171016' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS Week_1,
> COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20171016' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20171023' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS Week_2,
> COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20171023' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20171030' THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS Week_3
> -- Remember that Week 43 ends with 29 October, but we use < 30 October. 
> FROM `<<project-id>>.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
> WHERE  _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20171009' AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < '20171030'
> GROUP BY event_name
> ```

**ANSWER:**

After playing around with some of Mikhail's earlier suggestions, I got below code to work. This code runs quite fast for counting occurrences, but runs up to 40+ seconds for count distinct occurrences. I still need to somehow optimise this, but thought I would post this answer so long.

```
SELECT event.name as event_name, 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX 
  BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 * 7 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 2 DAY)) 
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 * 7 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY))
THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS Minus_3_Weeks,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX 
  BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 * 7 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 2 DAY)) 
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 * 7 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY))
THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS Minus_2_Weeks,  
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX 
  BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 * 7 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 2 DAY)) 
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY))
THEN user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id END) AS Minus_1_Week
FROM `<<project-id>>.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX 
  BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 * 7 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 2 DAY)) 
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY))
GROUP BY event_name;
```

Comment: from what I see  - you keep asking the same question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46548783/5221944 . Can you briefly explain what the difference here?

Comment: Agree with @MikhailBerlyant - it feels a little like Groundhog day in here :)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the answer. I refer back to my comment (Thanks for the update, still missing "Count of Event Occurrences" per week. Where would I actually count this value ?") and your reply "i truly think I have answered already your initial question. if you have new one - please post as new question".  So I posted a new question. I can't seem to figure out how to apply dynamic date ranges to the CASE WHEN at the top.  Another new part that was added is, that it should query the previous week, irregardless if I run the query on a Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday. Thanks :)

Comment: I see your point. It might be a way you are asking - your questions tend to be too broad and wordy. Hard to identify what exactly you need. Anyway - hope someone will jump in and help you

Comment: I had time to go over this question again. The answer above works now, albeit extremely slow.